# tfoot value from ajax function after dynamically add content to table i

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have inserted table values using ajax from database.i have to get total value in tfoot? How can i get that one?

```
enter code here
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSummerymiss_calls(){
deleteRow3();
var dtype=document.getElementById("date_3").value;
var dtype2=document.getElementById("date_33").value;
var stype=document.getElementById("server_33").value;

if(dtype>dtype2){
    alert("To date Should be greater than From date");
 return;

}
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function(){

          if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200){//if success
               ab=xmlhttp1.responseText;

                    if(ab.trim()=="" || ab.trim()==null){
                        alert("please select date and server!!!")  
                         }
                    else if(ab.trim()=="none"){
                        alert("no data found!!!")  
                     }
                        else{
                        a=ab.split(",");


                    for(var i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){  
                        var table = document.getElementById("table33");
                        var row = table.insertRow(1);

                        var cell1= row.insertCell(0);
                        var cell2= row.insertCell(1);


                         cell1.innerHTML = a[i];
                         cell2.innerHTML=a[i+1];

                        i+=1;


                    }      

            return true; 

                        }
          }
    }
        xmlhttp1.open("Post","mainController.jsp?action=getMisscallsSummery&dtype="
                + dtype + "&server=" +stype+ "&dtype2=" +dtype2 ,true);

        xmlhttp1.send(null); 


}
</script>
```

This coding says that Between date and server number which are given by user i have to count number of calls from database with date.finally i want sum of a[i] values in tfoot.please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use table.createTFoot() for the tfoot element

```
...

var total=0;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
var table = document.getElementById("table33");
var row = table.insertRow(0);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);


cell1.innerHTML = a[i];
cell2.innerHTML = a[i+1];

total += a[i]
}

var footer = table.createTFoot();
var frow = footer.insertRow(0); 
var fcell1 = frow.insertCell(0);
var fcell2 = frow.insertCell(1);

fcell2.innerHTML = total;

...
```

See for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/0y7428cb/

Comment: Theres a couple of other issues and bugs I corrected most to create a working example

Comment: It works but it added as string for example if values 12,365Then total will come as 12365.what can I do –

Comment: Conversion from string to number is a simple task, start by Googling?

Comment: i got that one thank you.one more question.. The above coding add rows to my table thead.I couldn't be able to add rows in tbody by using tag or given id to tbody.How can i do that?